# Is it possible to to retrieve commitId instead of runId when running az acr task?

Tags: azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I follow instruction from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cli/azure/acr/task?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-task-create) to create an image container in Azure Container registry whenever a commit is done.
Everything is working fine and I appreciate we could retrieve the Run.ID

```
az acr task create -t acb:{{.Run.ID}} -n acb-win -r MyRegistry \
-c https://github.com/Azure/acr-builder.git -f Windows.Dockerfile \
--commit-trigger-enabled false --platform Windows/amd64
```

I see also that we can use another tag like  {{.Run.Registry}} instead of {{.Run.ID}}.
I am curious to know which other tag exists. In my workflow i wonder if it possible to retrieve the commitID.

Is there anyone who succeed to retrieve the commitID ? I tester several combinaison but no luck.

Many thanks to the community.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself and found this link https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-reference-yaml.md#task-step-properties which explain clairly all variable can be used.